# Linking PMIDs with ORCID iDs

Tags: data-request, api, research, pubmed

I am looking for a dataset or API which would give the list of ORCID iDs  (=[Open Researcher and Contributor ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORCID)) given a PMID (=[PubMed identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubMed#PubMed_identifier)).

Comment: have you looked at orcid's api? [it supports pmid identifier](http://members.orcid.org/api/supported-work-identifiers)